# How to enable enforce_for_root under pam_pwquality.so in RHEL8 / CentOS 8?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

How can we enable enforce_for_root under pam_pwquality.so in a persistent way?

The goal is to force the root user set a strong password. I am aware that root is omnipotent and any restrictions can be overwritten, but it does not matter for my specific case .

I can edit /etc/pam.d/password-auth and add it there, but it's going to be overwritten on the next update.

Adding it to /etc/security/pwquality.conf also doesn't seem to have any effect in RHEL8 / CentOS 8.

I assume it needs to be done somehow via authselect / authconfig, but the documentation is very scarce and could not find any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, authconfig command is replaced by authselect utility.

Red Hat does not recommend to make modifications directly in PAM global files system-auth and password-auth available under /etc/pam.d/ directory.

You need to create a custom profile using authselect and make your configs in the files that get created in this custom profile.

The command below will tell you what profile you  are currently using:

```
authselect current
```

backup the current profile from above command:

```
sudo authselect apply-changes -b --backup=OUTPUT-FROM-AUTHSELECT-CURRENT-GOES-HERE.backup
```

Create a new ***custom*** profile based on the profile from the `authselect current` output above:

`sudo authselect create-profile your-own-password-policy -b sssd`     (sssd seems to be the default at least in RHEL 8.3)

your new profile gets created here: `/etc/authselect/custom/your-own-password-policy/`

Set your new custom profile as current profile:

```
sudo authselect select custom/your-own-password-policy
```

`authselect current` (this should show now your custom profile)

the files in `/etc/authselect/custom/your-own-password-policy/` specifically system-auth and password-auth are the ones that you **should** modify directly

when your modifications in the **system-auth** and **password-auth** in this location: `/etc/authselect/custom/your-own-password-policy/` are complete, issue this command:

```
sudo authselect apply-changes
```

in **both** `/etc/authselect/custom/your-own-password-policy/system-auth` and `/etc/authselect/custom/your-own-password-policy/password-auth` look for the line:

```
password    requisite   pam_pwquality.so
```

and append what you need **on both files**, below is an example I had to configure for our environment

```
password    requisite   pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 minlen=16 maxrepeat=3 maxsequence=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 difok=2 gecoscheck=1 reject_username enforce_for_root
```

for your specific question, you would only need:

```
password    requisite   pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 enforce_for_root
```

Below are the sources I used: (this by the way took me 2 days to figure out) the documentation for this is a catastrophe

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5027331

http://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-rhel8-guide-rht-ccp.html#!

[http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/linux_passwords_pam.html](http://www.deer-run.com/%7Ehal/linux_passwords_pam.html)